# Python сортировка списка дат

Tags: python, json, сортировка, дата

Подскажите, как отсортировать список выводимых дат

```
import json
import requests
import datetime as DT

from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

import operator

url = 'xxx.json'
r = requests.get(url)
data_json = r.json()
z = data_json['schedule']
x = z.keys()

for key in x:
    p = z[key]['name']
    a = data_json['schedule'][key]['dates']
    res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(p))
    print(p) 

#до этого момента все идет хорошо, проблема начинается дальше
for key in a:  
    b = a[key]['date']       
    c = a[key]['shows']
    b_list = list(b)

    print(type(b))         #<class 'str'>
    print(type(b_list))    #<class 'list'>
    print(b)               #16.12.2019 - выводит список таких дат, их и нужно отсортировать по порядку 
    print(b_list)          #['1', '6', '.', '1', '2', '.', '2', '0', '1', '9'] возвращает даты в таком виде
```

Задача, что бы даты отображались нормально и отсортировано :) Кусок JSON кода

```
{
  schedule: {
    1059: {
      id: "5852",
      name: "Холодное сердце 2 2D 6+",
      duration: "220",
      category: "",
      rental_doc: "124009619",
      dates: {
        17.12.2019: {
          date: "17.12.2019",
          shows: {
            49071: {
              id: "49071",
              time: "09:00",
              hallid: "4596",
              hallId: "1",
              hallName: "КИНОЗАЛ",
              prices: [
              {
                name: "Место",
                price: 200
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        15.12.2019: {
          date: "15.12.2019",
          shows: {
            151515: {
              id: "1515",
              time: "14:30",
              hallid: "228753+",
              hallId: "1",
              hallName: "КИНОЗАЛ",
              prices: [{
                  name: "Место",
                  price: 250
              }]
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: что значит "нормально и отсортировано". Что ненормально в датах сейчас?

Comment: Возвращает даты не по порядку, пример:

Холодное сердце 2 2D 6+
17.12.2019
15.12.2019
18.12.2019

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось достаточно просто:

```
for key in sorted(a):
    b = a[key]['date']      
    c = a[key]['shows']
    for key in c:
        d = c[key]['time']
        e = c[key]['prices'][0]['price']
        print(b, d, e, 'рублей' )
```

Надеюсь, что кому-то это когда-нибудь пригодится.